# How to inherit tab-completion from a subcommand to a function in zsh

Tags: autocomplete, zsh, tmux, zshrc

I have a function that is basically a wrapper around a tmux subcommand:

```
function tma() {
        tmux attach-session -t $1 || tmux new-session -s $1
}
```

I would like zsh to autocomplete with any open sessions that may exists as it currently does if I type `tmux attach-session -t` and start tabbing. I've tried

```
compdef tma=tmux
```

which understandably tries to autocomplete to tmux subcommands and

```
compdef tma=tmux attach-session -t
```

which gives the error message `compdef: unknown command or service: tmux attach-session -t`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Note that `tmux new-session -A -s "$1"` does the same thing as your function.

Comment: (Although it looks like the `tmux` autocompletion needs to be updated to allow completion the argument to `-s` in this case.)